# Universal solution to implement Royalties for ERC721 for trades on and off marketplace?

Tags: erc-721, royalties

The goal is to implement royalties in an ERC721 on any transaction, independent if it happened on a marketplace or peer-to-peer.

I can only find implementation/tutorials for royalties on a marketplace but there is no information about also charge royalties on peer-to-peer trades.

Is it even best practice to implement peer-to-peer royalties? and if yes, what is best practice implementing this requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. What you want is not possible.

You cannot differentiate between somebody transferring an asset to themself (at zero cost, and zero royalty due) versus transferring to somebody else as the result of an auction (royalty is due).

This basic idea is true on blockchains and also in the real world where cars and houses are often sold for the minimum reportable amount (i.e. $1 in USA).